# JSON and Unity , Showing image on game

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I have a Quiz Game app and I have images on the game. I want to show images.. Text are showing very well but the Images are not. here is my JSON C# Code.

[CLICK HERE THE PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEaFB.png)

To call my objects and variables.

```
 public TSRoundData[] myRoundData;

public TSPlayerProgress myplayerProgress;

private string mygameDataFileName = "TSdatabase.json";
```

My JSON code

```
  private void myLoadGameData()
{
    string myfilePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, mygameDataFileName);

    if (File.Exists(myfilePath))
    {
        string mydataAsJson = File.ReadAllText(myfilePath);
        TSGameData myloadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<TSGameData>(mydataAsJson);
        myRoundData = myloadedData.myRoundData;

    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Cannot load game data!");
    }
}
```

My JSON Script Code

```
      "questionImage":"Assets/ImagesQuiz/NoentryPlate.png",
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: What exactly is `TSGameData` really hard to pinpoint a problem when we have no idea how your classes look like especially if your are trying to populate them from JSON.

Comment: Also, I may be wrong but if you are loading resources using the `Resources.load` method, I don't think you need the file extension...

Comment: My question is what is the code to load images on screen when you are using JSON?

Comment: Well I need Images and Text but Images are not showing sir.

Comment: @Eddge TSGameData is just a another script that provides an array for TSRoundData[] if you would like you can watch the this tutorial where I get the code.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=No_COzTN-Is

Answer (score 0):

You holding your image path in json, soo try load it from resource folder.
Try like that:

```
    private Sprite myImage;

    private void myLoadGameData()
    {
        string myfilePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, mygameDataFileName);

        if (File.Exists(myfilePath))
        {
            string mydataAsJson = File.ReadAllText(myfilePath);
            TSGameData myloadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<TSGameData>(mydataAsJson);
            myRoundData = myloadedData.myRoundData;
            myImage = Resources.Load<Sprite>(myloadedData.myRoundData.questionImage);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Cannot load game data!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I will try I will let you know if it does work thank you

Comment: questionImage is an error sir how can I fix?

Comment: Moore it does not work sir.. is there something wrong with my JSON code? "questionImage":"Assets/ImagesQuiz/NoentryPlate.png",

Comment: Create folder Resources in project put your image to this folder and change image path in json file to "NoentryPlate.png".

Comment: Okay but how about this code in JSON will I change it? "questionImage":"Assets/ImagesQuiz/NoentryPlate.png" (ImagesQuiz is my folder for my images)

Comment: Get location of file and use "open with" and open it with text redactor. You also can open it with Visual Studio.
"questionImage":"NoentryPlate.png"

Comment: And how about this? how can I change this sir? myImage = Resources.Load<Sprite>(myloadedData.myRoundData.questionImage); 
  sorry I;m just new to unity and c# kindly help me with this thank you

Comment: I dont think that you need change this part, if path to your image is correct in json, it gonna load it. Or just send me debugging screenshot of your data to understood problem.

Comment: Hi @Archi Moore , I've Edit the question above can you just click the image from there? thank you sir, As you can see there's no image

Comment: try printing out the path to questionImage, and make sure that is the path to the image from your resource folder, also I believe you do not need the file extension so remove ".png"